# Convert to 'Strict' JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file, which the creators say is not 'Strict' JSON and have given python code to convert it into Strict JSON. I am new to python and keep getting error messages.

JSON example:

```
{'asin': '0078764343', 'description': 'Brand new sealed!', 'price': 37.98, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/513h6dPbwLL._SY300_.jpg', 'related': {'also_bought': ['B000TI836G', 'B003Q53VZC', 'B00EFFW0HC', 'B003VWGBC0', 'B003O6G5TW', 'B0037LTTRO', 'B002I098JE', 'B008OQTS0U', 'B005EVEODY', 'B008B3AVNE', 'B000PE0HBS', 'B00354NAYG', 'B0050SYPV2', 'B00503E8S2', 'B0050SY77E', 'B0022TNO7S', 'B0056WJA30', 'B0023CBY4E', 'B002SRSQ72', 'B005EZ5GQY', 'B004XACA60', 'B00273Z9WM', 'B004HX1QFY', 'B002I0K50U'], 'bought_together': ['B002I098JE'], 'buy_after_viewing': ['B0050SY5BM', 'B000TI836G', 'B0037LTTRO', 'B002I098JE']}, 'salesRank': {'Video Games': 28655}, 'categories': [['Video Games', 'Xbox 360', 'Games']]}
```

Python Code:

```
import json
import gzip
def parse(file_path=r"c:\Users\kiero\PycharmProjects\untitled\source\reviews_Video_Games.json.gz"):
  g = gzip.open(file_path, 'r')
  for l in g:
    yield json.dumps(eval(l))


  f = open("C:\\Users\\kiero\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\source\\reviews_Video_Games.json.gz",'w')
  for l in parse("C:\\Users\\kiero\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\source\\reviews_Video_Games.json.gz"):
    f.write(l + '\n')
```

The process keeps finishing with no edit to any files. Also, the script runs for less than a second. no error messages.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `path` really?

Comment: i am assuming path is meant to be the file path

Comment: meta_Video_Games.json.gz - You need to give the correct path to this file. Where is this file stored?

Comment: in the D drive. so path would be "D:\\meta_Video_Games.json.gz"

Comment: Try passing that to 'parse' function.

Comment: done that "def parse(path=r"D:\Users\meta_Video_Games.json.gz"):"

and i get the same error

Comment: Tried a few different ways of passing the file path I to parse. No luck

Comment: Do you trust the creators of the file? Running `eval` on their file could make the code do _anything_, including sending all your private files to them. Why don't they just create actual JSON?

Comment: Also it seems that the only problem in the example is that the file uses single quotes ('), while JSON requires double quotes ("). You could open the file in a text editor and use find+replace. Or they could.

Comment: @RemcoGerlichI need to do this to two files. one of the files is too large to open it a text editor

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems, the first is that using `eval` on data you get from other people is a huge security leak.

The second is that your code is indented wrong -- the part from `f = open(` onwards that calls `parse` shouldn't be indented, the current way it is part of `parse` and that function is never called (so nothing happens).

Third, you open the exact same file for writing (with `, "w"`) as you do on the next line for reading; but opening a file for writing empties it. So there is no data, what was there is destroyed.

Fourth, the file you open for writing has a ".gz" filename, but is written to as text, so the result would never be a gzip file.

Real code could look like:

```
import ast, gzip, json

INFILE = 'c://path/to/infile.gz'  # Gzip file
OUTFILE = 'c://path/to/other/file/out.json'  # Text file with generated JSON

in_f = gzip.open(INFILE)
out_f = open(OUTFILE, 'w')

for line in in_f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(line)  # Assuming the line is a valid Python literal
    out_f.write(json.dumps(data) + '\n')

in_f.close()
out_f.close()
```

Fifth, the end result would still have one data object per line, so the file as a whole would still not be valid JSON -- a JSON string represents one object. Each individual line would be valid JSON.

Comment: thank you got your help. I didn't realise eval was a security problem and thank you for pointing it out. I've tried this code and get this error.   raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string:

I think you've helped put me on the right path though so ill keep at it.